# How to assemble three videos with cross fade using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-fade

I am trying to assemble 3 videos (static title) (main feature) (static trailer). The title and trailer are encoded text with the main feature being h264 encoded (at 6Mbs). The title and trailer have nul audio encoded. The specific goal is a crossfade between the three segments. I have concat working fine, but adding crossfade is causing me issues.

How does `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+(4/TB)[v2];` work?

This code puts it together, but the bit rate and errors are wrong.

```
ffmpeg -y -i title.mp4 -i vid.mp4  -i trailer.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1920x1080 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=04:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=6:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; \  
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=2:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=30[over]; \
 [over][v0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
 [over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
 -vcodec h264_videotoolbox -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000000 -map [outv] merge.mp4
```

Comment: What are the durations of the three files?

Comment: Title is 15 seconds, vid is 20 minute, trailer is 30 seconds.